# Apply map, but only for temporary use

Tags: haskell

Given a function:

```
func :: [Int] -> Int
func x = minimum (map (+5) x)
```

And an input: `func [1,10]`.

I'm trying to get the output `1`, as `1+5` is lower than `1+10`, however, I can only work out how to output the value after the mapping function has been applied, whereas I only want the mapping to apply to my `minimum` usage and the output to be one of the original inputs.

How can I use a map temporarily, until I've found what I wanted, then return the pre-mapped version of that value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways, but the best is probably to use `Data.List.minimumBy`.  It takes a function that can compare two elements, then finds the smallest element using that comparison function.  It's pretty much purpose built for your situation.  It's type is

```
> :type minimumBy
minimumBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> a
```

Where

```
> :info Ordering
data Ordering = LT | EQ | GT    -- Defined in 'GHC.Types'
-- A bunch of instances that don't really matter here
```

so `Ordering` is just a basic sum type with three no-argument constructors.  Their names are pretty self explanatory, so all you need to do is pass it a function that returns one of these values:

```
comparer :: Int -> Int -> Ordering
comparer x y = ...
```

I'll leave the implementation to you.  You can then use it as

```
func x = minimumBy comparer x
```

Or simply

```
func = minimumBy comparer
```

Answer (score 2):

use `minimumBy (comparing f)` (where `f` would be `(+5)` for your example)

`minimumBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> a`

`comparing :: Ord a => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering`

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use a custom comparison function and `minimumBy`, as other commented. Note that in this case your transformation `(+5)` will be called  *twice* for each element in the list (roughly). E.g.

```
[4,3,2,1]
```

leads to

```
compare 4 3 => compare (4+5) (3+5) => compare 9 8 => GT
compare 3 2 => compare (3+5) (2+5) => compare 8 7 => GT
compare 2 1 => compare (2+5) (1+5) => compare 8 7 => GT
```

Note that `(3+5),(2+5)` are computed twice, above.

If the operation is expensive, and simply `(+5)` it may be beneficial to resort to a different approach. We can pre-compute the modified values while keeping the original ones if we build a list of pairs:

```
map (\x -> (expensive x, x)) [4,3,2,1]
```

Above, function `expensive` plays the role of `(+5)` in the original code. We can then take the minimum as follows:

```
snd $ minimumBy (comparing fst) $ map (\x -> (expensive x, x)) [4,3,2,1]
```

or even

```
snd $ minimum $ map (\x -> (expensive x, x)) [4,3,2,1]
```

The latter is slightly less general in that it requires that the list `[4,3,2,1]` is made of comparable elements, while the former only assumes that `expensive` produces something comparable.

However, note that the latter will not just return a random element of the list `[4,3,2,1]` which minimizes `expensive`, but it will be the minimum such element. That is, when `expensive x == expensive y`, the `minimum` function will break the tie comparing `x` and `y` directly. The former makes no such guarantee.